# My time slots are not booked

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I want to create a basic time slot booking system. But I've run into some problems.

I have created a calendar where I can see that something is happening on a speific date:

[image: calendar]

It takes the information from my database table. I'm using PHPMyAdmin, and I've added the date manually in there.

[image: Database]

As you can see in the table, I would also like to use a start time and an endtime.

If I click a date in my calendar, I create the add-event link like this:

```
<?php
if (isset ( $_GET ['v'] )) {
    echo "<a href='test.php . ?month=" . $month . "&day=" . $day . "&year=" . $year . "&v=true&f=true'>Add Event</a>";
    if (isset ( $_GET ['f'] )) {
        include ("test.php");
    }
    $sqlEvent = "SELECT * FROM calendar WHERE eventDate='" . $month . "/" . $day . "/" . $year . "'";
    $resultEvents = mysqli_query ( $mysqli1, $sqlEvent );
    echo "<br>";
    while ( $events = mysqli_fetch_array ( $resultEvents ) ) {      
    }
}
?>
```

Clicking this makes my url look somehting like this: `test.php%20.%20?month=04&day=18&year=2014&v=true&f=true#`

I've included my whole test.php file:

```
<?php 
$hostname = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$dbname = "calendar";

$error = 'Cannot connect to the database';

$mysqli1 = new mysqli ( $hostname, $username, $password, $dbname ) or die ( $error );

if (isset ( $_GET ['day'] )) {
    $day = $_GET ['day'];
} else {
    $day = date ( "j" );
}

if (isset ( $_GET ['month'] )) {
    $month = $_GET ['month'];
} else {
    $month = date ( "n" );
}

if (isset ( $_GET ['year'] )) {
    $year = $_GET ['year'];
} else {
    $year = date ( "Y" );
}

$dateToCompare = $month . '/' . $day . '/' . $year;

    echo "<br/><br/><h3>Reservations</h3>";
    $timearray =  array(8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22);
    $tablecolor = 1;
    echo "<table style='width: 90%;'>";
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>";
            echo "Time";
        echo "</th>";
        echo "<th>";
            echo "Status";
        echo "</th>";

    echo "</tr>";
    foreach ($timearray as $timearrays) {
        if($tablecolor %2 == 0) {
            echo "<tr>";
        }
        else {
            echo "<tr style='background-color: rgb(0,100,255); background: rgb(0,100,255);'>";
        }

            echo "<th>";
            if ($timearrays == 8) {echo "<h3>8-9am</h3>";}
            if ($timearrays == 9) {echo "<h3>9-10am</h3>";}
            if ($timearrays == 10) {echo "<h3>10-11am</h3>";}
            if ($timearrays == 11) {echo "<h3>11-12am</h3>";}
            if ($timearrays == 12) {echo "<h3>12-13am</h3>";}
            if ($timearrays == 13) {echo "<h3>13-14am</h3>";}
            //Develop your timeslots here to display as required
            echo "</th>";
            echo "<td>";

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM calendar WHERE eventDate='" . $dateToCompare . "'AND timestart >= $timearrays AND endtime <= $timearrays;";

            $result = mysqli_query($mysqli1,$sql);

            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
                echo "<a href='#'><h3 style='color: rgb(255,0,0);'>Reserve</h3></a>";
            } else {
                echo "<h3>Not Available, taken by someone</h3>";
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                    echo "<br />";
                }
            }
            echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        $tablecolor++;
    }
    echo "</table>";

?>
```

As you can see, I try to display my timeslots:  `$sql = "SELECT * FROM calendar WHERE eventDate='" . $dateToCompare . "'AND timestart >= $timearrays AND endtime <= $timearrays;";`

I think that I get my dates correctly from the URL, but I don't see any reservations for a given date.

[image]

I hope that some of you can help me out. And please ask, if I need to provide more of my code.

Or if anyone has a better idea on how to do this, please share.

I'm not really sure if I should be conserned about time. I basically just want the ability to click on "Reserve" and then reverse that specific time slot. So maybe a start and an end time isn't nessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to debug your application. But I guess the problem will probably be the `$timearrays` in the query you create. I don't think (haven't tested) it works that way.

My suggestion, print out `$sql` after you've initialized it and see what it returns. Then open PHPmyadmin (which I guess you're using, by the looks of your data) and see what it returns there.

Comment: Ahh. Thank you! :) I printet out the sql, and got this: SELECT * FROM calendar WHERE eventDate='04/18/2014'AND timestart >= 8 AND endtime <= 8;
SO then I realised that the end and start time needs to be the same in my database.